ApplicationPoolIdentity permission to access/create printer DC
I have a simple Windows console app that generates a pdf file and it uses printer DC for its inner workings to render appropriate boundaries or font sizes or something. I do not know how exactly it works on the inside, but I must use it and can not substitute it for an alternative.
When I run in directly through cmd it works fine.
When I run it through a ASP.NET webapp it fails to access or create a printer DC. It says so in the log file and output file is all crooked.
If in IIS Manager I change application pools identity to a NetworkService or a regular Windows user, then it works fine, but the customer wants to use ApplicationPoolIdentity.
On some of my older test machines it works fine with ApplicationPoolIdentity, but I can not make it work on any new machine. I tried Windows 10 and 11, Windows Server 2019 and 2022. In IIS Manager I set DefaultAppPool advanced setting Load User Profile to True,
and in default printer properties Security tab I added IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool and gave it all permissions and restarted the computer. It still can not access printer DC.
Anyone knows how to give ApplicationPoolIdentity permission to access/create printer DC?

Try looking in Event Viewer for relevant logs to narrow down the issue.

Adding Internet Printing to IIS might be an alternative. This will expose installed printers in a virtual directory and will be controllable via IIS manager, authentication methods can be chosen. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/printing/manage-connect-printers-use-web-browser. You can also restrict IP access as mentioned in the link so just IIS can use the printers vDir in case such a restriction is needed.
